# Parameter not passing from @Url.Action to method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, actionresult, url.action

I'm trying to pass a field value from my model via `@Url.Action` to a method in my controller but it continues to come through as null. The link I'm sending the field value from looks like this

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" 
       onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("NewName", "Home", new { name = Model.name})'" />
```

The method in the controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult NewName(string name)
{
     // .   
     // .
}
```

Each time the value for name passed to the method is null. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass your value this way to the `Controller`:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("NewName", "Home")?name=@Model.name';" />
```